# Using valid token but still receiving invalid_auth response from Slack's files.upload API

Tags: python, python-requests, slack-api

I have to post an excel sheet to my Slack Channel. The token which I'm using to send the excel file doesn't seems to be working as I'm always getting invalid_auth error from the API. I don't understand why its happening because I'm able to send images to my channel easily using the same token (with chat.postMessage API of Slack).

This is the code which I'm using to send:-

```
with open('XL File.xlsx', 'rb') as xl:
  my_file = {
      'file': xl
  }

  payload = {
      'filename' : 'XL File.xlsx',
      'token' : my_token
      'channels': [channel_name],
      'filetype': 'xlsx',
      'initial_comment': "This is the excel sheet for your reference"
  }

  rq = requests.post('https://slack.com/api/files.upload', params = payload, files = my_file)
```

Comment: Some troubleshooting suggestions: check that the channel id is correct. Is your bot in the channel? Do you have the correct scopes? Does using the xoxp vs the xoxb token make a difference?

Comment: I had checked the scopes... the only one required for bots for files.upload method(files:write) is already present for my bot. I've also verified the channel multiple times, and they are valid (tried using # channel_name as well as channel id C####, all give the same result).
I think that bot auth tokens are all beginning with xoxb .. so I don't think that this is a problem, also as I mentioned, I'm currently using the same token to send messages using chat.postMessage API. Thanks for suggesting, really appreciate it. I would though, check with xoxp once, would inform you if it worked. Thx..

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to send the token as a query parameter? Slack API prefers tokens to be sent in the Authorization HTTP header of your outbound requests. However, you may also pass tokens in all Web API calls as a POST body parameter called token. https://api.slack.com/web.

Comment: I'm sending the token in the JSON payload, I'm following the same code which I mentioned in my question. I'd already tried sending it as an Authorization HTTP header, but for that I got an error stating the bot is not in the channel. This was weird as it doesn't happen when I use the chat.postMessage API. So I went back to the old code (i.e. the one mentioned in the question I posted).